# UV map breaks when importing blender model that has a rig

Tags: blender, unity-game-engine

I've been making some models in blender for a game I'd like to create. The problem is that, in Unity 5, when ever I try to add a UV-map to a model that **is** rigged, the map breaks and sometimes just displays one colour. However, when I import my model without the rig attached, it works perfectly.

Any ideas what the issue could be? I've using the .blend files in Unity and have been creating the UV-maps in blender.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you considered exporting everything as .fbx instead? Have not seen .fbx giving same headache as .blend.

Comment: I may have. I recall .fbx giving me some other errors but I'll try that again and check. Thanks.

Comment: try to follow the the export and import part of this tutorial  http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BlenderAndRigify.html hope that helps